# Flatten list of lists of lists into single list

Tags: prolog

Trying to flatten list of lists of lists into single list with following modification. The lowest level list should merge into one item of resultant list and dash should be added between them. More you can see from following:

```
Input:
L = [[[A],[B]],[[C],[D]],[[E],[F]],[[G],[H]]] 

Expected output:
Res = [A-B,C-D,E-F,G-H]
```

Here is my code:

```
toList([],_).
toList([H|T],Out) :-
    toList1(H,Out1),
    newOut2 = [Out|Out1],
    toList(T,newOut2).

toList1([],newOut1).
toList1([[A],[B]],Out1) :- 
    newOut1 = [A-B],
    toList1([],newOut1).
```

Should work like `toList([[[A],[B]],[[C],[D]],[[E],[F]],[[G],[H]]], Res)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually describe this relation with a single predicate, let's call it `lists_pairs/2`. There are two cases to cover:

1. If the list of lists is empty then the list of pairs is empty as well.
2. If the head of the first list is of the form `[[A],[B]]` then the head of the second list is `A-B` and the relation has to hold for the tails of the lists as well.

You can express this in Prolog like so:

```
lists_pairs([],[]).                        % case 1
lists_pairs([[[A],[B]]|Ls],[A-B|Ps]) :-    % case 2
   lists_pairs(Ls,Ps).
```

Your example query yields the desired answer:

```
?- lists_pairs([[[A],[B]],[[C],[D]],[[E],[F]],[[G],[H]]], Res).
Res = [A-B, C-D, E-F, G-H].
```

You can also use this predicate in the other direction:

```
?- lists_pairs(L, [A-B, C-D, E-F]).
L = [[[A], [B]], [[C], [D]], [[E], [F]]].
```

And the most general query works as well:

```
?- lists_pairs(L, P).
L = P, P = [] ;
L = [[[_G22], [_G28]]],
P = [_G22-_G28] ;
L = [[[_G22], [_G28]], [[_G43], [_G49]]],
P = [_G22-_G28, _G43-_G49] ;
L = [[[_G22], [_G28]], [[_G43], [_G49]], [[_G64], [_G70]]],
P = [_G22-_G28, _G43-_G49, _G64-_G70] ;
.
.
.
```