# Turn Nested list to a list of lists PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog, nested-lists

i need some help with this, i have a list of this kind:

`[[[4,11,9,7],[4,13,8,6],[4,12,10,5]],[[3,12,8,7],[3,11,10,6],[3,13,9,5]],[[2,13,10,7],[2,12,9,6],[2,11,8,5]]]  %(is a list with three lists, and inside of each list are other three list)`

And i´m trying to get one like this:

`[[4,11,9,7],[4,13,8,6],[4,12,10,5],[3,12,8,7],[3,11,10,6],[3,13,9,5],[2,13,10,7],[2,12,9,6],[2,11,8,5]] %(a list with nine lists).`

%Currently i have this kind of append, but the output isn't near what i need:

```
appendL([],[]).  %->base case
appendL([H], H). %->base case
appendL([H,H2|T], [L3|L1]):-
    append(L,L1,L3),
    append(H,H2,L),
    appendL(T, L1).
```

This one give:
`[[[4,11,9,7],[4,13,8,6],[4,12,10,5],[3,12,8,7],[3,11,10,6],[3,13,9,5],[2,13,10,7],[2,12,9,6],[2,11,8,5]],[2,13,10,7],[2,12,9,6],[2,11,8,5]]`

And you can notice that there is three list that appears two times

Comment: You're looking into a flattening operation for lists, e.g. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080759/flatten-list-of-lists-of-lists-into-single-list).

Answer (score 2):

Can use DCG as per [Get elements from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777077/get-elements-from-list-of-lists/9787502#9787502)

```
seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) --> [E], seq(Es).

seqq([]) --> [].
seqq([Es|Ess]) --> seq(Es), seqq(Ess).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
% Show first 99 elements of a list
?- set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options, [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(100), attributes(portray)]).

?- phrase(seqq([[[4,11,9,7],[4,13,8,6],[4,12,10,5]],[[3,12,8,7],[3,11,10,6],[3,13,9,5]],[[2,13,10,7],[2,12,9,6],[2,11,8,5]]]), L), length(L, Len).
L = [[4,11,9,7],[4,13,8,6],[4,12,10,5],[3,12,8,7],[3,11,10,6],[3,13,9,5],[2,13,10,7],[2,12,9,6],[2,11,8,5]],
Len = 9.
```

Note: If not wanting to use DCG, then should use a difference list instead of append/2, as per https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flatten/2

Answer (score 0):

Guess what, `append(K,X)`. Make the work where;

```
K=[[[4,11,9,7],[4,13,8,6],[4,12,10,5]],[[3,12,8,7],[3,11,10,6],[3,13,9,5]],[[2,13,10,7],[2,12,9,6],[2,11,8,5]]]
X= [[4,11,9,7],[4,13,8,6],[4,12,10,5],[3,12,8,7],[3,11,10,6],[3,13,9,5],[2,13,10,7],[2,12,9,6],[2,11,8,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something [like this](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/THGcRMRN.pl):

```
flatten( Xs , Ys ) :- flatten(Xs,Ys,[]) .

flatten( []    ,    Fs  , Fs ) .
flatten( [H|T] ,    Fs  , F1 ) :- nested(H), !, flatten(H,Fs,F0) , flatten(T,F0,F1) .
flatten( [H|T] , [H|F0] , F1 ) :-                                  flatten(T,F0,F1) .

nested( [ [_|_] | _ ] ) .
```

That lets you say things like this:

```
L = [
      [
        [a] ,
        [b]
      ],
      [
        [
          [c] ,
          []  ,
          [d] ,
          [
            [e]
          ],
          [g]
        ]
      ]
    ],
flatten( L , F ) .
```

And get

```
F = [
      [a] ,
      [b] ,
      [c] ,
      []  ,
      [d] ,
      [e] ,
      [g]
    ]
```

Comment: The requirement is to "flatten" by 1 level, rather than flatten completely into a plain list.

Comment: @brebs — not so. He starts with a list of 3 lists, each of which contains 3 lists — `[ [ [a],[b],[c] ], [ [d],[e],[f] ], [ [g],[h],[i] ] ]` — and the O.P. wishes to reduce that to a simple list of 9 lists: `[ [a], [b], [c], [d], [e], [f], [g], [h], [i] ]`. This code meets the requirement (for any depth of nested lists-of-lists).